# Ограничить число создаваемых потоков

Tags: c#, многопоточность

У меня есть событие, в котором я получаю изменяемое значение. При каждом событии создаю поток и проверяю одной функцией, дошло ли значение до какого-нибудь уровня. Событие возникает каждую секунду, а порой и 2-3 события в секунду. В самой функции я поставил `lock`. Соответственно, потоки не успевают обрабатывать так быстро и при отладке я увидел, что создано их штук 40. Как можно ограничить создание потоков до 10 там. Ну, или как-нибудь по-другому реализовать задачу?

```
private void waitTrade(bool isNewBar) 
    {
        lock (lockerTrade)
        {
         .............
        }
    }

Thread th = new Thread(() => waitTrade(false));
th.Start(); // две строчки прописаны в самом событии
```

Comment: Хмм, а если ограничить число потоков, тогда часть событий будут теряться? Это допустимо?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov ну, там скорее можно брать и каждое десятое событие, их слишком много и часто появляются,

Comment: события можно обернуть в Task (если нужно). вызывать task заданное количество раз. (но пока я не экспериментировал над этим)

Comment: @dgzargo ну вот я всё же попробовал с ThreadPool. А потом понял, что намного проще создать Thread, отслеживать его окончание и если что его тоже инициализировать.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `ThreadPool`, и добавляйте ему задачи. Вы можете даже выставить вручную максимальное количество потоков методом `SetMaxThreads` (по умолчанию выставляется значение зависящие от количество ядер процессора).